# 2-way switch Boolean switching circuit

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

I was a bit surprised to see a circuit question appear in an Abstract algebra test paper:

> A hall light is controlled by two switches one upstairs and one
>   downstairs. Design a Boolean circuit so that the light so that light can be
>   switched on or off from upstairs or downstairs.

I'm not completely sure how to approach this problem. I was thinking along the lines of "say bulb is on if both A and B are same (either $0$ or $1$).

So I get the Boolean expression as $(A\wedge B)\vee (A'\wedge B')$ from the truth table.

Would the circuit be two switches $A$ and $B$ in series which as a whole is parallel to A' and B' in series?

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Look up what a "Boolean Circuit" is - google image search is helpful. It is a diagram with various logic gates (e.g. AND, OR, NOT), which in your case will have two inputs (A and B) and one output (the light status). Your boolean expression can be almost directly converted to  a boolean circuit diagram.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I'm not looking for circuits with logic gates. Just switching circuit will do. Similar to the ones given in Gilbert Nicholson I guess

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Anyhow, is my expression $(A\wedge B)\vee (A'\wedge B')$ correct?

Comment: Your expression is a correct one (though you can simplify it a bit with De Morgan's law). The question is explicitly asking for a boolean circuit, i.e. a diagram with logic gates, not an electrical circuit.

Comment: It surprised you? As in, it was never discussed in class? Or covered in the text? It’s a pretty standard example of application of Boolean algebra.